# How to switch to drafting table mode in LightTable?

Tags: lighttable

How can I switch to "Draft Table" mode in LightTable? Tried different sources (Ruby, Closure, Python). With Vim mode turned on and off. But I never see mode buttons in the right-bottom corner.

Comment: What do you mean by draft mode?

Comment: @lovelyVector I mean the mode when the code is split by functions on a single tab (in demo video it is called Draft Table mode). On video http://www.chris-granger.com/lighttable/ it is on 03:23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video was just to demonstrate the concept, before the actual thing had been written. Those features aren't real (yet).

Comment: Thanks for info, I was filling my self in information vacuum.